# Configure contextual filter: Content: Nid

Tags: views

I have two content types called product and product_feature
I am on something like www.something.com/product_name/product_feature_name
I am on the product_feature landing page and I want to display product_name and product ID

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Please would you consider revising your post, at the moment it's difficult to find an actual question in there. Adding some background to what you're doing (how the two content types are related for example) would be useful too

Comment: I am using D7 and Product and Product Feature is related each other and Product Feature has node_ref field to product ID